# Drag&Drop list that sets model properties based on order?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, dom

I'm trying to implement a list of items on a web page in which each item on the list is reorder-able via drag and drop.  The current placement of an item within the list should set an 'interest' property on the item's model.

I've never built anything like this before and not really sure where to start or what approach to take.  Any guidance would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this walkthrough which was very helpful:

http://webtempest.com/sortable-list-in-ruby-on-rails-3-almost-unobtrusive-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [acts_as_list gem](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) to simplify reorder process at backend, and [jQuery.sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) at frontend